# How to fade WPF background image?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to fade background WPF image?

My XAML looks like this:

```
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="themes\backpic.png" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        </ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
```

I have tried something like:

```
 <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="pics\bl.png" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <!-- some code here-->
            </ImageBrush.Transform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start a DoubleAnimation of the ImageBrush's Opacity property:

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Opacity"
                        To="0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
    ...
</Grid>
```